# Deep learning with Tensrorflow and cifar10

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to classify cifar10 images with softmax but the model is not learning anything.

the code below prints

```
 0 None
 1 None 
 2 None
```

And so on. How can i fix my code or figure out why it's always None?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10, mnist
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,3072])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
#reshaping the y_train and x_train
y_train = y_train.reshape((5000,10))
x_test =x_test.reshape(10000,3072)
x_train = x_train.reshape(50000,3072)
y_test =y_test.reshape(1000,10)

# Data normalization
x_train = x_train/255
y_train = y_train/255
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3072,10]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W1)+b1)
# this is a cross entropy
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))
# let's train to get the minimum loss using back+forward propagation
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(50):
       print(j,sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x : x_train , y_ : y_train[j]}))
```

Comment: Please do not format your text as quote (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will return None, because the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize) say it will **return an Operation that updates the variables in var_list**

If you want to see the loss value, you could write following:

```
_, loss = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x : x_train , y_ : y_train[j]})
print(j, loss)
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: I am trying to print my accuracy but i can't figure out how,Do you have any idea?.Thanks

Comment: [tf.compat.v1.metrics.accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/accuracy) is what you want, try to find what you need in documents first, so you don't have to ask every questions that similar in nature : )

Comment: I really appreciate your help too but I am new to tensorflow and deep learning

Comment: I added in for loop     print(i,sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:x_test,y_:y_test[i]}))
and changed the cross_entropy to correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,-1), tf.argmax(y_,-1))
but got 0.0 accuracy every time . but i can't understand why

Comment: Forgive me if I don't have much time for every problems you encountered, it seems like you have not reached the normal level of programming just yet, my advise is to start from some simple [tutorials of classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) on Tensorflow V2 instead of V1 (using keras, it gonna be much easy for beginner), meanwhile try to learn how to using the documentation when coding, learn some basic skill first before you moving deep, best wish for your ML journey, have a good day : )

Comment: i just told what i did and every time the accuracy is 1 or 0.Anyway thanks for your help,but i am stuck with this almost 2 weeks,and i am student,I am not trying to be rude or something  or getting the solution without trying ,and i appreciate your help, Thank you alot sir.